# C# ASP Project using MySql 5.5 - Parameter query syntax

Tags: c#, mysql, syntax

Some of my queries are working with different syntax for parameterized queries, and I can't seem to work out the syntax for the parameterised queries for C#, MySql 5.5.

For example, what is the syntax for:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE (column1 = @param1) AND (column2 = @param2)
```

Is the @parametername the correct way to declare them?  After would I simply need to:

```
sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", 'apples');
sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", 'oranges');
```

When using a query that uses subqueries and aliases in the select clause need different parameter syntax in the where clause?

Thanks.

---

EDIT:

Okay this is the query I'm having the trouble with:

```
SELECT postcode, suburb, streetname, categorycode, DATE_FORMAT(dateRecorded, '%d/%m/%Y') AS 'Date Recorded', DATE_FORMAT(dateLastModified, '%d/%m/%Y') AS 'Date Last Modified', status FROM incidentdetails WHERE (postcode = @postcode) AND (suburb = @suburb) AND (categorycode = @categorycode) AND (status = @status)
```

I'm adding the parameters:

```
    sqlFillRelated.Parameters.AddWithValue("@postcode", int.Parse(PostcodeTxtBox.Text.ToString()));
    sqlFillRelated.Parameters.AddWithValue("@suburb", SuburbTxtBox.Text.ToString());
    sqlFillRelated.Parameters.AddWithValue("@categorycode", IncidentTypeDropList.Text.ToString());
    sqlFillRelated.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", "Open");
```

If I remove the WHERE clause the query returns the table as expected, but it just seems like these parameters aren't being picked up, because it always returns an empty set.  I can copy the query exactly and run it without problems through the server explorer, adding in the parameters manually.

```
    string sqlFILL = "SELECT postcode, suburb, streetname, categorycode, DATE_FORMAT(dateRecorded, '%d/%m/%Y') AS 'Date Recorded', DATE_FORMAT(dateLastModified, '%d/%m/%Y') AS 'Date Last Modified', status FROM incidentdetails WHERE (postcode = @postcode) AND (suburb = @suburb) AND (categorycode = @categorycode) AND (status = @status)";
    string sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM incidentdetails WHERE (postcode = @postcode) AND (suburb = @suburb) AND (categorycode = @categorycode) AND (status = @status)";
    MySqlConnection mycon = new MySqlConnection(sqlconnection);
    mycon.Open();
    MySqlCommand selectRelatedCmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, mycon);
    MySqlCommand sqlFillRelated = new MySqlCommand(sqlFILL, mycon);
    int matches = 0;
    selectRelatedCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@postcode", int.Parse(PostcodeTxtBox.Text.ToString()));
    selectRelatedCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@suburb", SuburbTxtBox.Text.ToString());
    selectRelatedCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@categorycode",IncidentTypeDropList.Text.ToString());
    selectRelatedCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", "Open");
    sqlFillRelated.Parameters.AddWithValue("@postcode", int.Parse(PostcodeTxtBox.Text.ToString()));
    sqlFillRelated.Parameters.AddWithValue("@suburb", SuburbTxtBox.Text.ToString());
    sqlFillRelated.Parameters.AddWithValue("@categorycode", IncidentTypeDropList.Text.ToString());
    sqlFillRelated.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", "Open");


    matches = int.Parse(selectRelatedCmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
    if (matches == 0)
    {
        matchingIncidentPanel.Visible = false;  
    }
    else if (matches >= 1)
    {
        matchingIncidentPanel.Visible = true;
    }

    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(sqlFILL, mycon);
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    da.Fill(table);
    g.DataSource = table;
    g.DataBind();

    mycon.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL connector uses ? instead of @ to mark the parameter names.

Try like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE (column1 = ?param1) AND (column2 = ?param2)
```

[MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand.html)

And about subqueries - I know that at least in MsSQL there was some problem with passing parameters to subqueries ( I think it simply wasn't possible) so this might also apply to MySQL, but this is pure speculation.

Comment: I did try that, but then some of my queries weren't working properly.  I'm using MySQL 5.5 and just found an example in the documentation of them using the @ parameters, but they don't seem to be working properly in my queries either...  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-net-programming-prepared.html

Comment: I've edited my original post with the additional code.  Thanks.

Comment: I'll try to test the code that you provided. To me it seems perfectly fine, so without testing I can't help you any more.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the parameter names were fine, but the command just wasn't initialising.  I've got the code working now, as below - thanks for the help :).

```
    public void getRelated()
{
    string sqlFILL = "SELECT incidentID, postcode AS Postcode, suburb AS Suburb, streetname AS Street, categorycode AS Category, DATE_FORMAT(dateRecorded, '%d/%m/%Y') AS 'Date Recorded', DATE_FORMAT(dateLastModified, '%d/%m/%Y') AS 'Date Last Modified', status AS Status FROM incidentdetails WHERE ((postcode = @postcode) AND (suburb = @suburb) AND (categorycode = @categorycode) AND (status = @status))";

    MySqlConnection mycon = new MySqlConnection(sqlconnection);
    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    mycon.Open();
    MySqlCommand sqlFillRelated = mycon.CreateCommand();

    sqlFillRelated.Parameters.AddWithValue("@postcode", int.Parse(PostcodeTxtBox.Text.ToString()));
    sqlFillRelated.Parameters.AddWithValue("@suburb", SuburbTxtBox.Text.ToString());
    sqlFillRelated.Parameters.AddWithValue("@categorycode", IncidentTypeDropList.Text.ToString());
    sqlFillRelated.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", "Open");

    sqlFillRelated.CommandText = sqlFILL;
    da.SelectCommand = sqlFillRelated;

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    g.DataSource = ds;
    g.DataBind();
    mycon.Close();
}
```